# no more than one class can extend AsyncTask in an Android project?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is there any case such that: both *class A* and *class B* can extend AsyncTask at the same ? Or else, should it be one *class C* that extends AsyncTask?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes, they can extend at same time. What do you think might not allow that?

Comment: whenever I try to call execute() method over an object of A and after call it again over an object of B, SocketTimeOutException occurs. What I am trying to do is that making GET requests to obtain JSON data by using Retrofit.

Comment: Here is the problem that I solved by using **AsyncTask** [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936848/outer-method-execute-before-override-inside-method-in-java/48938586#48938586]

Answer (score 0):

Any number of classes can extend AsyncTask at the same time (or any other class). Extending means that the new class inherits fields and methods of super-class and can override super-class methods. The same applies to AsyncTask as well.